# Grammatical function of "as"

Tags: grammar

What's the grammatical function of "as" in the following sentence?

> *The furniture makers in those early decades of the 1600’s were known as “joiners,”
>   for the primary method of constructing furniture, at least among the English of this
>   time, was that of mortise-and-tenon joinery.*

Any response would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its grammatical function is of a preposition, introducing the preposition phrase *as joiners*, which is a complement of *known*.